# how to block YouTube annotation ads only

Tags: youtube, advertisements, extension

I'm figuring out a way to allow youtube to play its video ads, and videos ads only. So I'm trying to disable all annotation or other ads that block some parts of the video and requires me to click it away.

1 I'm using nano adblocker. Is there a filer/way to tweak this option?

2 Is there an extensions/scripts on Chrome or Firefox that can work it out?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that there are any extensions available "off the shelf" which intentionally block some YouTube ads, but not others. Most users expect an ad blocker to block *all* ads, not just some of them.

You may be able to customize the blocklist used by an existing ad-blocking extension to disable the rules used to block YouTube video ads. However, these blocklists change frequently (along with YouTube's ad delivery systems), so this will be an ongoing task.